# Scrapy don't follow links to images

Tags: python, scrapy

Is there a way in Scrapy to not follow `<a>` tags pointing to images?

For example:

`<a href="http://jamsphere.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Franki-Dennull-PROFILE.jpg">`

My code at the moment:

```
for a in set(response.xpath('//a/@href')):
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Obviously I can add a hard coded check but was wondering if there is a built in option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [LinkExtractor](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html), by default it filters out the common image / video / audio / file extensions.

Look [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.5.1/scrapy/linkextractors/__init__.py#L21) to see the ignored extensions.

Comment: If I use a `deny=` in the `LinkExtractor` I think that overrides that. Is there a way to have my `deny` not override this?